# How can I using angular when I want to click?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

I'm a beginner to learn this component. And I going to try to create a online book shop like this link https://www.fishpond.com.hk/Books , and I'm facing some problem now. Could you guys please help me? And first in my website, it have backend and frontend, and now I can show all book , insert new book, and now I want to know how can I do when I click the title of the book and what I have to do to transfer to get that book detail.

How can I click the title and I will see those book detail on the book-details page. And I hope get the isbn code to find that book.

My code here
HTML

```
    <h1>All Books</h1>

<ul *ngIf="books" class="info">
    <li *ngFor="let book of books">
       <p><img [src]="book.image" class="bookimg"></p>
        <a routerLink="/book-detail"><h3>{{ book.title }}</h3></a>
        <p>{{ "By "+ book.author }}</p>
        <span class="price-block" >{{ "HK$" + book.price}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  h1Style: boolean = false;
  books: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getBooks().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log({data});  //show data
      this.books = data
      //console.log(this.books);
    })
  }
```

And I have created a component for book-detail

```
    <h1>Book-detail</h1>
<div *ngIf="books" class="book-detail-block">
  <div *ngFor="let bookrecord of books" class="book-record">
    <h1>{{bookrecord.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{bookrecord.image}}</p>
    <p>{{bookrecord.author}}</p>
    <p>{{bookrecord.price}}</p>
    <p>{{bookrecord.isbn}}</p>
    <p>{{bookrecord.description}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book-detail',
  templateUrl: './book-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book-detail.component.scss']
})
export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  h1Style: boolean = false;
  books: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getOneBook().subscribe(data => {
      this.books = data
      console.log(this.books);
    })
  }

}
```

I can get the data in the service but how can I implement in show component

```
 export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  h1Style: boolean = false;
  books: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('-0-----' + this.books)
    this.data.getBooks().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log({data});  //show data
      this.books = data
  })

}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnoJ2.png)

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: How can I click the title go to a page call book-detail, and I will see those book detail on the book-details page. And I hope get the isbn code to find that book. How can I do that? @LazarLjubenović

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the issue and you've already solved it but in the off-chance that you havent i'll hopefully provide some guidance.

What you want for accessing an individual item when clicking the title is to use a click-event on the tag representing the title, probably the h1-tag. It looks something like this:

```
<h1 (click)="getBookDetail(bookrecord)">{{bookrecord.title}}</h1>
```

The line above hooks up a clickevent to a function called getBookDetail and takes the individual object as a parameter, as of now this will render an error saying there's no function named getBookDetail(), so you'll need to create it in the component.ts file that corresponds to the view probably the homecomponent.ts and it looks like this:

```
getBookDetail(book: any) {
   console.log(book);
}
```

If you now reload the application and click the title you'll see the individual book-object being logged in the console. What you'll need after is to set up routing if you havent already (you get the question to include app-routes module when creating the project) and to create a path for the bookDetailComponent. If you have routing in place add an array of routes as following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/books', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'books', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'book/:id', component: BookDetailComponent },
];
```

The first item in the routes array will match any route that is empty like localhost:4200 and redirect to the HomeComponent, and the other two arrays are routes for the individual component.

And if you dont have a routing-module i suggest you follow angulars tutorial for adding in-app navigation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5.

And for making the click on the title actually navigate to the bookcomponent you first need to inject the Router class, so if you go back to the homecomponent you'll see an constructor (if not create one), add the router class like:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

And in the getBookDetail function you can remove the console.log and add:

```
getBookDetail(book: any) {
   // Wrong path this.router.navigateByUrl('/book/' + book.isbn);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/bookdetail/' + book.isbn);
}
```

All that you need now is to get the isbn from the url and fetch one book with that identifier, but i'll leave those steps to you, everything you'll need is in the angular tutorial i linked previously. Good luck and if anything is confusing or you have any questions feel free to ask.

Added a stackblitz showing my idea:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2znl2?file=src/app/books/books.component.ts

Comment: HI Tommi, may I know where can I add the const routes?

Comment: And I got the this error in the console.  [core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'bookdetail/bookrecord1531910246'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'bookdetail/bookrecord1531910246] may I know what happen

Comment: In backend, I have a route to get the book like this. Handler_Book.collectionConnect().then(() => {route.get('/bookdetail/bookrecord', (req, res) => { Handler_Book.bookOne(req, res) })

Comment: What does HomeComponent.ts look like now?

Comment: constructor(private data: DataService, private router: Router) {}                                                             getBookDetail(book:any) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/bookdetail/bookrecord' + book.isbn)
  }

Comment: You want to remove "bookrecord" from the string so the navigateByUrl looks like: '/bookdetail/' + book.isbn). From your other comment i think you are mixing the routes in backend with the ones you are creating in angular they are separate. You use the routes in backend for fetching data with some sort of http-call, typically this is done with a service.

Comment: but I use postman to get the data is using localhost:10888/bookdetail?isbn=006230125X to get the record. did I need to add ? and = at the navigateByUrl?

Comment: Again, the routes that you specify in angular are just so you can navigate between pages, the route you are using for retrieving data is something else and for that you probably want a service. Like how you in your DataService have getBooks() you want a getBook(isbn) that returns one book object, like this

getBook(isbn) {
  return this.http.get('localhost:10888/bookdetail?isbn=' + isbn);

Comment: I have no idea.. i still not work.. in my home.component.ts getBookDetail(book:any) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/bookdetail?isbn=' + book.isbn)
   }     and In my dataservice.ts getBookDetail(isbn) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:10888/bookdetail?isbn=' + isbn)
  }      what I have do wrong.. in my HTML did I type wrong ? <a routerLink="bookdetail?=isbn" (click)="getBookDetail(book)"><h3>{{ book.title }}</h3></a>

Comment: The error message in console. core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'bookdetail'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'bookdetail'

Comment: The error you are seeing is because of the navigateByUrl() because its trying to match the url /bookdetail?isbn=1234 but if you look in your routes array the only two routes you have (should atleast) is /books and book/:id so when you type in bookdetail?isbn in the navigateByUrl it cannot find anything. The navigate should just contain the string '/book/' + book.isbn, have you tried changeing the navigateByUrl to this.router.navigateByUrl('/book/' + book.isbn); ?

Comment: Yes I have tried . `core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'book/1524763160'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'book/1524763160'`

Comment: My bad, navigateByUrl takes an absolute path, so try and change it to navigateByUrl('bookdetail/book/' + book.isbn); If there's still a problem, mind sharing a repository or something where the code is? Kind of hard to know what could be the issue with just snippets.

Comment: I've added a stackblitz with an working example, check it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2znl2?file=src/app/books/books.component.ts . As you can see there's a separate file called "app-routing.module.ts" that contains the routes for the application. Also i made an mistake with the navigateByUrl as you can see its changed to this.router.navigateByUrl("bookdetail/" + book.isbn); without the leading books path. Hopefully this will help you go forward.

Comment: Hi Tommi, I want to get only one book of the bookdetail how can I only get the only one?

Comment: For that you want to checkout https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments so you can retrieve the isbn (which im assuming is the id for getting one book). And add a function in your dataservice that can retrieve one book from the backend, probably with this adress localhost:10888/bookdetail?isbn=006230125X. Also if you feel my answer to your original question helped you, you are welcome to accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Tommi, I have fix the problem and also can get the one book detail but I facing another problem. I have some capture from the console, I see and array can be get , but now how can I choose that one ? `I have update at main`

Comment: Its hard to know without seeing the DataService, could you show it? It looks like you've moved in the getBooks() to bookDetail when you want the getOneBook() like previously.

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bookdetail?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbookdetail%2Fbookdetail.component.ts) I have upload some code you may see it? I think the wrong is in bookdetail ngOnintit, the ` this.data.getOneBookDetail().subscribe` should be permit to get one book. But I tried a lot on this. I don't know what I have need to type in getOneBookDetail(xxxx)

Comment: did you can be access to the link?

Comment: I could access but your example has errors..  First in Angular you use the "any" type if you dont know what's provided by the server not "Object" so you need to change that in the home.component.ts and in the dataservice, in the getBooks method you need to add a return type like return this.http.get<any[]>('url to my backend');  And in the home.component.html you have a routerLink you dont need as you have the getBookDetail method, you can use routerLink instead if you want but then you need to fix the syntax as per this link: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink .

Comment: As for your problem with bookdetail, in the example you have the right idea but you've mixed up the different components. Looking at the example you provided: From home.component.ts you get all books, here you can click on one title and go to bookdetails.component.ts and here you should get that book. Why do you then get the bookdetail in home.component? The example i provided should give you a general idea of what you want.

Comment: That means I don't need a webpage for the bookdetails? Since in my home page I haven't show all the detail there, show I want a page to show more detail about it

Comment: I can got the value now return from the data.service.ts of console.log("Get successful value returned in body", val); I can see the val object, but how can I implement and show on bookdetail page?

Comment: I've updated my example ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c2znl2?file=src/app/books/books.component.ts) where you can see how you use the activatedRoute to get the parameter in the url. The flow goes like this: books.component, here you list all books. bookdetail.component, here you fetch one book via the getOneBookDetail(isbn) method that you have in the dataservice, does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Tommi, thanks for the help first. But I saw yours example, I tried to click the booktitle and I see it can route to book-detail but here can you explain how can you only show one  book record on the book-detail page?

Comment: In my example if you click on one book you can see that it logs only that book right? So you have the data you just need to bind it to a variable and then display it in the html for the component called "book-detail.html" preferrably with string-interpolation like you use in the for-loop for all books. If you feel lik i've helped you i would appreciate if you accepted my answer (checkmark next to the answer). Thanks.